# Java calendar add function issue

Tags: java

In my beginner java programming class, we are supposed to print out today's date, then add 100 to the date, and then print it out the 100 days later date. I got the date to print out, added 100, but when I tell it to print out the new date, it stays the same. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong at all.

```
import java.util.*;


public class DateCalc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      //Calendar object named today representing today's date and time
      GregorianCalendar today = new GregorianCalendar();

      //Print the current date
      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      int dayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
      int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
      int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
      int weekday = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
      System.out.println("Today's date is " + month + "/" + dayOfMonth + "/" + year + " which is day " + weekday + " of the week.");

      //Print the date and weekday that is 100 days from today
      today.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 100);
      System.out.println("The date in 100 days is " + month + "/" + dayOfMonth + "/" + year + " which is day " + weekday + " of the week.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you really in a Java programming class where they're teaching you to use classes like `Calendar` and `GregorianCalendar`?  Those classes have been obsolete for many years now.

Comment: You called the `add` method of `today` … and then you didn’t do anything to read the new state of `today`.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use Calendar anymore. It was old and had a lot of issues. Use the [new Java time api](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) which is not only efficient but also easy to read. Here is my code that adds 100 days to current date.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now(); // Create a date object
        System.out.println(date); // Print date 

        date = date.plusDays(100); // Add 100 days
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2019-09-17
2019-12-26
```

If you insist on using Calendar
Here is the code
You were not updating variables and expecting them to give new date

```
// Print the current date
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int dayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int weekday = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
System.out.println("Today's date is " + month + "/" + dayOfMonth + "/" + year + " which is day " + weekday
        + " of the week.");

// Print the date and weekday that is 100 days from today
GregorianCalendar today = new GregorianCalendar();
today.add(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 100);
dayOfMonth = today.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
month = today.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + 1;
year = today.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR);
weekday = today.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
System.out.println("The date in 100 days is " + month + "/" + dayOfMonth + "/" + year + " which is day "
        + weekday + " of the week.");
```

**Output:**

```
Today's date is 9/17/2019 which is day 3 of the week.
The date in 100 days is 12/26/2019 which is day 5 of the week.
```

Answer (score 1):

When you define

```
int dayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int weekday = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

You're `get()`-ing values from `cal`, and *storing* them in variables. Later, you call `add` on `today` (not `cal`), but then print `dayOfMonth`, `month`, `year`, and `weekday`, which hold the exact same values as before - you haven't done anything to change them. Calling `add()` does not change these variables. It wouldn't even if you called `add()` on `cal` instead of `today`. It only changes the result of `get()` calls to the calendar.

To get the updated values after calling `add()`, you will need to `get()` them from whichever calendar object you `add()`-ed to.

Answer (score -1):

If you are adding days to a calendar, use:

```
today.add(Calendar.DATE, 100)
```

not `DAY_OF_MONTH`

Comment: I doubt whether this will fix OP's problem.  Have you tried it?

Comment: `GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(); cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 100); System.out.println(cal.getTime());` shows me Thu Dec 26 16:36:53 EST 2019. Less than 100 shopping days to Xmas!

Comment: While the code in your comment works, neither that nor your answer addresses the questioner’s real issue (and “helping” the questioner use the poorly designed and long outdated `Calendar` class may not really be helping…).